# Bubble Sort in PHP and Python

Tags: php, python, bubble-sort

As far as I can tell, these two programs should do exactly the same thing. However, the Python version works and the PHP one doesn't. What am I missing please?

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

my_list = [2,3,5,4,1]
bubbleSort(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

---

```
<?php
// Bubble Sort
$my_list = [2,3,5,4,1];

function bubble_sort($arr){
    $size = count($arr);
    for($pass_num = $size - 1; $pass_num >= 0; $pass_num--){
        for($i = 0; $i < $pass_num; $i++){
            if($arr[i] > $arr[$i + 1]){
                swap($arr, $arr[i], $arr[$i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}


function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a];
    $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
    $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}

bubble_sort($my_list);
print_r ($my_list);
```

Comment: The only time I have actually done a bubble sort was at college. So I guess this is homework right?

Comment: No actually. Self study from an over-40!

Comment: Not familar with PHP but the way you code it I guess declaring `&$arr` in swap means the argument is passed by reference? If so then the array is not passed by reference in the declaration of the PHP sort function and as a result you don't have the array sorted after the function returns.

Comment: Ok first obvious one is you have use `$arr[i]` in a couple of places instead of `$arr[$i]` It would be useful to look at the error messages to self fix those

Comment: For some reason I get no error message with the `i`s instead of `$i`s. As for passing by reference, I believe that is what the `&` should do. So maybe I should put the swap code in the main function?

Comment: @Robin No, it's not about the swap. You should pass $arr by reference to the PHP bubble sort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort is in fact working, but as you dont pass a reference to the `bubble_sort($arr)` function you never get to see the actual result. Telling `bubble_sort()` that the array is being passed by reference means you are changing `$my_list` and not a copy of `$my_list`

Oh and you had some compile errors, using `$arr[i]` instead of `$arr[$i]`

```
// Bubble Sort
$my_list = [2,3,5,4,1];

function bubble_sort(&$arr){    // <-- changed to &$arr
    $size = count($arr);
    for($pass_num = $size - 1; $pass_num >= 0; $pass_num--){
        for($i = 0; $i < $pass_num; $i++){
            if($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]){
                // also changed this line to pass just the indexes
                swap($arr, $i, $i+1);   
            }
        }
    }
}


function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a];
    $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
    $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}

bubble_sort($my_list);
print_r ($my_list);
```

If you are testing this on a live server where error reporting is turned off add these lines to the top of any script you are developing, while you are developing it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And the compile errors would have shown on the web page

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. That `&` in the function parameter could have taken weeks for me to work out! Also I see that I was mixing up the elements with their indices in the swap.

Comment: No problem, us over 40's gota stick together

Answer (score 0):

**Bubble Sort Php**

```
$data_set = [3,44,38,5,15,26,27,2,46,4];

function bubble_sort($data_set){
    $number_of_items = count($data_set);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_items - 2; $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j <= $number_of_items -($i+2); $j++){
            if($data_set[$j] > $data_set[$j + 1]){
                $temp = $data_set[$j];
                $data_set[$j] = $data_set[$j + 1];
                $data_set[$j + 1] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return $data_set;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r(bubble_sort($data_set));
echo '</pre>';
```