# how to implement bubble sort in php with minimal complexcity?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I have an array of 5 elements. On that i want to apply bubble sort with min complexity

Currently what i am doing is

```
function bubbleSort(array $arr)
{
    $n = sizeof($arr);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
        for ($j = $n - 1; $j >= $i; $j--) { 
       //some fuzzy logic here
        }
      }
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001294/bubble-sort-implementation-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bubble Sort in PHP and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790316/bubble-sort-in-php-and-python)

Comment: If you MUST use bubble sort (which is o(n^2)) but still improve complexity you can follow the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614342/bubble-sort-adaptive-java/51614865#51614865